# how to solve this questions about NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = 5;
    Point2D.Double[] p;
    p = new Point2D.Double[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter x of vertice " + (i + 1) + ":");
        p[i].x = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter y of vertice " + (i + 1) + ":");
        p[i].y = input.nextDouble();
    }

}
```

I actually don't get what's going wrong with these codes. NullPointerException always happens at "p[i].x = input.nextDouble()". Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I bet p[i] is null because p was not initialized. Just because you've said p has size elements, it does not mean all its positions are filled with initialized objects of type Point2D.Double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize your array elements first.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    p[i] = new Point2D.Double();
    System.out.println("Please enter x of vertice " + (i + 1) + ":");
    p[i].x = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter y of vertice " + (i + 1) + ":");
    p[i].y = input.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` is currently an array of `null` values, as you haven't assigned anything to it yet.

So when you call `p[0]`, you are getting a `null` back. You can't call `null.x` because null doesn't have a `.x`.

You should do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter x of vertice " + (i + 1) + ":");
    double x = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter y of vertice " + (i + 1) + ":");
    double y = input.nextDouble();

    p[i] = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
}
```